# regex for Excel to remove all but specific symbols after a specific symbol?

Tags: excel, macos

I have stings like this which are addresses, e.g.:

```
P.O. Box 422, E-commerce park<br>Vredenberg<br><br><br>Curaçao
Adelgatan 21<br>Malmö<br><br>211 22<br>Sweden
Läntinen Pitkäkatu 35 A 15<br>Turku<br><br>20100<br>Finland
```

I am interested in Country only. Country always comes last after a `<br>` tag.

Note, that there can be several such tags preceding this last value (e.g. 1st example string).

Is there a good way to do a formula may ve along those lines:

1. Identify end of string
2. Loop a character back until one reaches ">" character
3. Cut everything else (including the ">" encountered)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `RegEx` to do this if it's always the last part of the string.

You can get it with String modifiers doing

```
Sub Test()
    Dim str As String, str1 As String, str2 As String
    Dim Countries As String

    str = "P.O. Box 422, E-commerce park<br>Vredenberg<br><br><br>Curaçao"
    str1 = "Adelgatan 21<br>Malmö<br><br>211 22<br>Sweden"
    str2 = "La¨ntinen Pitka¨katu 35 A 15<br>Turku<br><br>20100<br>Finland"

    Countries = Right(str, Len(str) - InStrRev(str, "<br>") - 3)
    Countries = Countries + vbNewLine + Right(str1, Len(str1) - InStrRev(str1, "<br>") - 3)
    Countries = Countries + vbNewLine + Right(str2, Len(str2) - InStrRev(str2, "<br>") - 3)

    MsgBox Countries
End Sub
```

Obviously  this will need to be updated for how your data set is stored. You can loop through the dataset and use the string modifier on each line

Answer (score 0):

A formula works too. If a string in A1, write in B1:
`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"<br>",REPT(" ",100)),100))`

Modified using an approach taken from here:
https://exceljet.net/formula/get-last-word